# CSS Horizontal List/Nav with unwanted bottom padding

Tags: css, horizontallist

Trying to get rid of some weird bottom padding under the nav items, which is being caused by the `navigation .span` style (which is the one that makes things work so I can't get rid of it). I want the nav items to be flush to the top and bottom.

I've been using this bit of coder for the longest time and I think it's either the first time I notice the padding or I've just been sweeping it under the rug.

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/arminvit/B2sAn/

Quick look at the code below:

CSS

```
/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
width:100%;
clear:both;
float:left;
text-align:justify;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.navigation * {
display: inline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.navigation ul {
list-style-type: none; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.navigation li {
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
color:white;
background:black;
padding:5px;
margin:0px;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.navigation span {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="navigation">

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>

        <span></span>

    </div><!--END navigation-->
```

Comment: Sorry, why do you need the empty span? Because, if you remove it, the gap disappears.

Comment: You should **never change the strucuture of your html just for styling** (especilally add empty elements). Styling is the responsibilty of css, and should be kept separate from your content. So I have to agree wit @AndrewGibson, why do you need the span? just remove it!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure why I need this span. It's all a piece of code I grabbed from somewhere that worked for my needs. All I know is that if I take out the span off the HTML the nav items don't do full-justify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure of what you want, but seems to be a mixed or left overs of differents method .
So if you want to text-align justify your links, drop all about floatting.
http://jsfiddle.net/69LjY/
some to read : http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

```
/* NAVIGATION */

    .navigation {
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }

    .navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:0;
    }

    .navigation li {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    color:white;
    background:black;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:1.2em;
    }
.navigation ul:after {content:'';padding-right:2700px;}/* line-height 0 + this avoid gaps under , padding , use widest screen width you like*/
```

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, this does work. Just for peace of mind... The "padding-right:2700px" is not too hack-y or break something somewhere? (It doesn't seem to, but just want to double-check).

Comment: it avoid to give width:100%; wich seems to give element 1px height :)

Answer (score 1):

I added another navigation bar to your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arminvit/B2sAn/) with some CSS classes and markup that, I think, give it the effect you were looking for. (CSS below)

```
.test_nav{
   background:orange;   
}
.test_nav_bar{
   list-style-type: none;
}
.test_nav_bar li{
   display: inline-block;
   background: gray;
   margin-left:50px;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Obviously you should play around with the spacing etc.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

remove `display: inline-block;` from `.navigation span`

Comment: But then it doesn't do full justify